# How to limit user on DatePicker to can only choose date before today_date - 18 years

Tags: android, android-widget

How to limit on DatePicker to cannot choose date in future. I have DatePicker in activity which is used for registration. What to do so user cannot pick date of birthday if user has less that 18 years ( for example cannot pick date after today_date - 18 years )?

Comment: convert the set date in millis and check with current date in millis. calculate interval between two millis.

Answer (score 2):

You didn’t mention which API level. On Honeycomb and later, [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) has setMin/MaxDate methods you can use to restrict the permissible range.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you got the answer till now. Following might be useful to others as well:
If you want to disable user to pick a date 18 years after today, here is what you may do.

Get time from 1-JAN-1970 to 18 years from now (in milli seconds)

```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+18,cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 
            cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 0);
   long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

set it as max allowed date in datepicker

```
   datepicker2.setMaxDate(time);
```

Hope it helps to anyone else looking for a answer

Answer (score 0):

Count the year before 18 from now (current year) by  int minYear = currentYear - 18; And then set that date with (Min year , current month, current day) as the max limit of the date picker.

```
    private static void setMaxLimitInDatePicker(DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    int minYear = currentYear - 18;
    int minMonth = currentMonth;
    int minDay = currentDay;

    calendar.set(minYear, minMonth, minDay);
    long minDateInMilliSeconds = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    // Set 18 years from today as max limit of date picker
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(minDateInMilliSeconds);
}
```

Comment: please consider explaining your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged.